# PHP 500 internal server error when calling a php function

Tags: php, chrome-gcm

I have a problem lately I have created a function in my php file, and I am trying to call the function from the same file but when I call it i just get 500 internal server error.

```
function messageThem($match, $message) {


if(isset($match) & isset($message)) {
$query = "SELECT gcm FROM gcm_users";
$result = $con->query($query, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

$regID = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$regID[] = $r["gcm"];
}



$url = "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send";
$api = "REMOVED. API KEY MAY NOT BE SHARED";
$data = array('match' => $_POST['match'], 'message' => $_POST['message']);
$fields = array('registration_ids' => $regID,'data' => $data);
$headers = array('Authorization: key=' . $api,
             'Content-Type: application/json');



printf("np bro");

//curl connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

$resultCurl = curl_exec($ch);

  if ( curl_errno( $ch ))
{
    echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
}

curl_close($ch);

echo $resultCurl;


}


}
messageThem("1200","message goes here");
```

The only thing I achieve from this is an internal server error. But then if I remove the function and just run the code it works perfect. So it likes when I want to call it it gives me and internal server error.

Comment: You probably need to make `$con` accessible in the function,it`s a scope issue.

Comment: peek httpd's error log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is raised because `$con` variable is not defined and You call `query` method on it - definitely a scope problem.
Probably You got error:
`Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object`

So there are two solutions:

1. You have to use

`global $con;`

2. or You have to pass `$con` as third argument to the function.

I assume, that `$con` is an object of db connection here.